# Can I control how Session skills are chained?

Tags: tokyo-mirage-sessions-fe

If there are multiple paths for a Session chain to resolve, is there any way for me to control which Session skills are used? For example, if I have the following Session skills on Tsubasa and Touma

```
Tsubasa      Touma
Sword-Wind   Sword-Fire
Fire-Lance   Wind-Lance
```

and I have Itsuki use a Sword skill to start a Session, how I control whether Tsubasa or Touma go second or third?